# XSLT custom date formatting - GSA

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to format the XSLT in dynamic navigation to render dates in a particular format. My code generates the following error:

```
 "An unknown error occurred."
```

XSLT code  is:

```
<xsl:template name="CustomDate-DN">
    <xsl:param name="d"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-date($d, '[D01] [MN,*-3] [Y0001]', 'en', (), ())"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PV" mode="display_value">
    <xsl:param name="js_escape"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- Customizations - Fancy Date -->
        <xsl:when test="../@T = 4">
            <xsl:call-template name="CustomDate-DN">
                <xsl:with-param name="d" select="@V"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <!-- End of Customization -->
    ...
```

If I replace

```
 <xsl:value-of select="format-date($d, '[D01] [MN,*-3] [Y0001]', 'en', (), ())"/>
```

with

```
<xsl:value-of select="$d"></xsl:value-of>
```

It seems to work, but the date is in the wrong format.

I would appreciate some help. Thanks.

**UPDATE**: My date currently looks like `dd/mm/yyyy`. I am using xslt 2.0. I think the problem is I passing a string to the format-date function. The function requires a date. I am not sure how to convert `dd/mm/yyyy` string into date.

Comment: Are you sure you are using an XSLT 2.0 processor? format-date is new in XSLT/XPath 2.0. And if you use an XSLT 2.0 processor, how does `$d` respectively `@V` look exactly when you get the error?

Comment: currently it looks like dd/mm/yyyy. I am using xslt 2.0. I think the problem is I passing a string to the format-date function. The function needs a date. I am not sure how to convert dd/mm/yyyy string into date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string which represents a date in the format `dd/mm/yyyy` is *not* a valid `xs:date` and cannot be used in `format-date()`.

But you can *parse* the string and convert it to an [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) date, which *is* a valid *xs:date* type. One way to achieve that in XSLT 2.0 is to use `<xsl:analyze-string>` to extract the year, month and day parts with a regular expression. Then you can rebuild the date in the ISO 8601 format and store the result in a new variable which you can pass to `format-date()`:

```
<xsl:template name="CustomDate-DN">
    <xsl:param name="d"/>

    <xsl:variable name="iso-date">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="$d" regex="(\d{{1,2}})/(\d{{1,2}})/(\d{{4}})">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(3)"/>
                <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
                <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="format-date($iso-date, '[D01] [MN,*-3] [Y0001]', 'en', (), ())"/>
</xsl:template>
```